# UIImage поворачивается при загрузке с помощью NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: swift, uiimage

Доброго времени суток!
Наперед, вот проект на GitHub: https://github.com/megas781/Civilia

Такая проблема: при загрузке изображения из файла с помощью `NSKeyedUnarchiver`(т.е. при загрузке приложения), оно поворачивается, опираясь на свою "source" ориентацию. Хотя когда загружаю `image` в ячейку из другого `image` (смотреть `AddCMViewController.createButtonTapped` метод), все нормально. Как сделать так, чтобы при загрузке из файла изображение отображалось корректно? Как бы вы решили эту проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Была подобная проблема, когда загружал картинки через АПИ.
Решил ее очень просто - повернул изображение на 90 градусов. Вот пример кода -

```
ImageView.transform = ImageView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2)
```